# Test 'done' callback function of a jQuery deferred object with sinon.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, callback, sinon, spy

I have this piece of CoffeeScript code in one of my Backbone views:

```
myMethod: ->
     # some code here

     $.when(
          # ...
     ).done(
          @myCallback
     )
```

and I wanna test that myCallback is called in the done block.

I'm not sure how to do this in Mocha.js + Sinon.js. I was able to spy on jquery and check that the when method is called:

```
spy = sinon.spy($, 'when')
@view.myMethod()
spy.called.should.be.true
spy.restore()
```

But I can't do the same with the done block because, if I have unterstood it right, it's related to the deferred object returned by the when method.

I also tried something like this:

```
# NOT WORKING CODE
stub = sinon.stub($.Deferred(), 'done').returns
     myCallback: sinon.stub()
@view.myMethod()
stub.called.should.be.true
stub.restore()
```

but still getting:

```
expected false to be true
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: shouldn't you be using `@myCallback` instead of `@myCallback()`? Just a blind guess. But $.done doesn't exists. `done` is part of the promise object, so I guess it would be `$.Deferred().done`

Comment: @pocesar you're right, it's a typo (once I haven't used copy and paste.. sorry!). I agree with you about the deferred, I wrote it like that to make clear what I would like to achieve. I tried to spy on that and I also tried to stub the promise object, without success. Further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can stub `$.when` similarly as you would do an ajax request. Firstly you have to stub `$.when` and return a `$.Deferred` object.

```
var stub = sinon.stub($, "when", function (event) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    result.args = event;
    return result;
})
```

After calling the function you want to test, get the return value of the specific `$.when` call which will be the deferred object. Resolve it manually and you can do the assertion of the `@myCallback` being called.

```
@view.myMethod()

// Get first when call
var call = $.when.getCall(0).returnValue;

// To return successful when call (having used .done() )
call.resolve();
```

Answer (score 0):

Mock it in the view class?

```
#arrange
view = new View
view.myCallback = sinon.spy()

#act
view.myMethod()

#assert
view.myCallback.called.should.be.true
```

Whether the callback was called as a deferred `done` handler or any other way is an implementation detail. All that should matter that the method was called (with correct arguments, if you choose).

Comment: it still seems that the function hasn't been called. Maybe the done callback could not be triggered for some reasons?

Comment: Maybe your test found a bug :) Btw. I'm not sure my sinon assert is correct, just copied from your question. Only ever used sinon with Jasmine asserts.

Comment: If so, I hope to find it out :) The function is working, it has been written without tests before I could notice it and I don't want to leave it uncovered. The assert is fine, used many times before, in fact I get a "good error".

Comment: Is the deferred an async operation? Do you need to declare tests as async with Mocha?

Comment: Or maybe if the deferred is async, the callback is not YET called at the time of assert. Don't know how to handle that with Mocha, though.

Comment: Maybe you're right and it's not yet called when I assert my expectation. How would you deal with that (even with jasmine)?

Comment: In Jasmine you would use `waitsFor`. See https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs